# add/delete rows with fields that are pick lists in a dynamic form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dynamic-forms

Hi I am trying to create a dynamic form where you can add a second and third row, etc, and it keeps the same properties as the first row (picklist, text).  Here is what I have so far but it is not working, anyone know how to fix this?  Thank you!

**HTML**

```
<form>
<div id="myRow">
    <div class="col-md-1 ">
        <div class="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control-label" for="info_1">Make</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="info_1">
                    <option disabled selected>Choose one...</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 ">
        <div class="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control-label" for="info_2">Model</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="info_2">
                    <option disabled selected>Choose one...</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 ">
        <div class="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control-label" for="info_3">Type</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="info_3">
                    <option disabled selected>Choose one...</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 ">
        <div class="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control-label" for="price">PRICE</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" id="price">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="btnAdd" class="button-add" onclick="insertRow();">add</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var index = 1;
function insertRow(){
            var table=document.getElementById("myRow");
            var row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
            var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
            var t1=document.createElement("input");
                t1.id = "info_1"+index;
                cell1.appendChild(t1);
            var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
            var t2=document.createElement("input");
                t2.id = "info_2"+index;
                cell2.appendChild(t2);
            var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
            var t3=document.createElement("input");
                t3.id = "info_3"+index;
                cell3.appendChild(t3);
      index++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `div` tag, and it has no function `insertRow`. If you want to use `insertRow` function you should use `<table id="myRow">` tag instead of `<div id="myRow">`. 
If you don't want to change your html using `table` than you should write your own `insertRow` and `insertRow` functions.